# Inexplicable behavior of Xcode UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

There is a simple application with a TableView, in the code I create a FooterView (with a button inside) and a HeaderView (with a UICollectionView inside). With the selected simulator Iphone 11,12, X - everything works well, the sizes of FooterView and HeaderView match the given ones. But if I select IphoneSE - dimensions go astray, FooterView disappears altogether, HeaderView becomes microscopic. Please help

- here is the footer config

```
private func configureUITableViewFooter(){
    let footerView = UINib(nibName: "FooterView",
                           bundle: .main).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! FooterView
    footerView.delegate = self
    footerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.view.bounds.width, height: 200)
    OrderTableView.tableFooterView = footerView
    
}
```

- here is header config

```
    private func configureUITableViewHeader() {
        let headerView  = UINib(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! HeaderView
        headerView.delegate = self
        headerView.dataForHeaderCollectionViewCell = selectedObject
        headerView.configureView()
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.frame.height/3)
        OrderTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }
```

- here is viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            OrderTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OrderTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OrderTableViewCell")
            self.viewModel = ViewModel(data: selectedObject!)
            configureNavigationController()
            configureUITableViewHeader()
            configureUITableViewFooter()
        }
```

- here is result for iphone se:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncnaq.jpg)
- here is result for iphone 11:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9e33.jpg)

Guys, what do you think is the matter?

Comment: Print the value of `self.view.bounds`. Could it be that you are using that value too soon before layout has occured?

Comment: I printed ("\ (self.view.bounds)") in viewDidLoad, FooterConfig, HeaderConfig - result: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This becase in your storyboard or in xib file of your viewController are show as size of iphone 12. In viewDidLoad, the tableView Size are load with the size in iphone 12, so in iphone 12 or other device with same size they display correct, and in iphone SE they display not correct. Try to set header and footer when the tableView size are correct, maybe in ViewDidAppear for example

Comment: Thanks! This helped to fix the problem!